Jest Unit Test of a React component fails because of MUI SvgIcon: TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'useContext')
I am testing a React Component that implements MUI. Once I added a MUI SvgIcon (RefreshIcon), the unit test fails because of: "TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'useContext')"
To avoid invalid hook calls, I wrapped all my components with this :
// Create a theme for the ThemeProvider
const theme = createTheme();

// Utility function to render the component with necessary providers (to avoid invalid hook calls)
const renderWithProviders = (ui: React.ReactElement) => {
  return render(
    <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
      <BrowserRouter>{ui}</BrowserRouter>
    </ThemeProvider>
  );
};

Do I need to wrap the Ui with another type of providers?

Do components with other (non-icon) material ui components fail in the same way? Or just mui icons? Either way this is possibly related to having different versions of mui packages at different levels of your project. Also can happen if you are using npm link anywhere. Assuming using npm and not yarn/pnpm try npm ls @mui/material in your project with the test file and edit question with result. Also the results of  npm ls react and npm ls react-dom. If you were previously getting invalid hook calls, that further raises suspicion (highly) of a  package management/resolution issue.
